# Having Dax inquiries

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have a table in the following structure:

| Name | Reg.Date | Term.Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Date |  |
| A |  | Date |
| A | Date |  |
| B | Date |  |
| C | Date |  |
| C | Date | Date |
| C | Date |  |
| D | Date |  |
| D |  | Date |
| E | Date |  |
| E | Date | Date |
| E | Date |  |
| E |  | Date |

I would like to compare the lastest dates between 'Reg.Date' and 'Term.Date' under each 'Name'
if Latest Re.Date => Latest Term. Date then 'active' if not 'inactive'

end result 1 would be like something like:

| Name | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| A | Active |
| B | Active |
| C | Inactive |
| D | Active |
| E | Inactive |

then, I would want to count how many inactives and if possible, count it by inactive per month(using the months on the dates on Term.Date)

Is there a way to accomplish this using DAX language on PowerBI?